# how to draw multi images/bitmaps without background color?

Tags: c++, blend, direct2d

I have multi images/bitmaps whose background is white color, now I want to draw these to render target one by one without copy white color. I tried to achieve:

1. `SetPrimitiveBlend(D2D1_PRIMITIVE_BLEND_MIN)`, reference [D2D1_PRIMITIVE_BLEND enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447008(v=vs.85).aspx), but the non-white pixels of the image who draw late will not cover the before image, intersection will show another color.

   ```
   _deviceContext->SetPrimitiveBlend(D2D1_PRIMITIVE_BLEND_MIN);

   _deviceContext->BeginDraw();  
   _deviceContext->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));  
   _deviceContext->DrawBitmap(Bkg, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), 1.0);  
   _deviceContext->DrawBitmap(Img1, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), 1.0);  
   _deviceContext->DrawBitmap(Img2, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), 1.0);  
   hr = _deviceContext->EndDraw();
   ```
2. then I tried another method as example [Direct2D composite effect modes sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Direct2D-Image-Effects-4819dc5b), it works fine for only one foreground image and one background image. But I need draw multi foreground images.

   ```
   _deviceContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Blend, &_EffectBlend);  
   _deviceContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1ColorMatrix, &_EffectFore);  
   _deviceContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1ColorMatrix, &_EffectBack);  
   _EffectBlend->SetValue(D2D1_BLEND_PROP_MODE, D2D1_BLEND_MODE_DARKER_COLOR);     
   _EffectBlend->SetInputEffect(0, _EffectBack);  
   _EffectBlend->SetInputEffect(1, _EffectFore);     
   _EffectBack->SetInput(0, Bkg);    
   _EffectFore->SetInput(0, Img1);   

   _deviceContext->BeginDraw();  
   _deviceContext->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));  
   _deviceContext->DrawImage(_EffectBlend, D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR);  
   _deviceContext->EndDraw();
   ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? Where are the relevant parts of your code so far?

Comment: Again: Look here to learn how to post and format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to post the relevant parts of your code inline in your question. You can do so by editing your own questions.

Comment: i may find the solution, d2d framework support alpha channel:
set white color pixel's alpha to "0.0f";
draw image/bitmap/line/rectangle/blush and so on element pixel's alpha to "1.0f";    
   
 `_deviceContext->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White, 0.0f));    
 _deviceContext->DrawBitmap(_pIBkg, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), 1.0);  
 _deviceContext->DrawBitmap(bitmap3, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), 1.0);  
 _deviceContext->DrawBitmap(bitmap, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, _width, _height), 1.0);`